# CentOS 6: cannot send email with PHPMailer but ok on laptop

Tags: centos, phpmailer, centos6

I am designing a website on aliyun.com. This website includes a function to send emails with PHPMailer. It perfectly works on my laptop (a Mac Book Air running XAMPP) but not on the live server (a fresh CentOS 6) with exactly the same php files (SMTP host, password, ...). Here is below the log I got from PHPMailer in verbose mode:

```
2015-04-08 02:59:42 Connection: opening to smtp.mywebsite.com:587, t=300, opt=array (
                                      )
2015-04-08 02:59:42 Connection: opened
2015-04-08 02:59:42 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.aliyun-inc.com MX AliMail Server(10.194.100.112)
2015-04-08 02:59:42 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO mywebsite.com
2015-04-08 02:59:42 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.aliyun-inc.com
                                  250-8BITMIME
                                  250-AUTH=PLAIN LOGIN XALIOAUTH
                                  250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN XALIOAUTH
                                  250-PIPELINING
                                  250 DSN
2015-04-08 02:59:42 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
2015-04-08 02:59:42 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 Ready to start TLS
2015-04-08 02:59:42 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2015-04-08 02:59:44 SERVER -> CLIENT:  ��:%4P���pGC#mLa+�%YF�l �0���I
2015-04-08 02:59:44 SMTP ERROR: QUIT command failed:  ��:%4P���pGC#mLa+�%YF�l �0���I
2015-04-08 02:59:44 Connection: closed
2015-04-08 02:59:44 SMTP connect() failed.
```

Although I spent many hours on internet looking for a solution, I cannot figure out where the problem comes from... I am using the latest release of PHPMailer and the function mail in command lines works well (I mean I receive them), so where the problem could from?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Alplob

Comment: "Many hours" didn't apparently include reading [PHPMailer's docs](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting).

Comment: It's odd that your server does not advertise STARTTLS, but accepted the command anyway! It's also strange that it advertises AUTH without requiring STARTTLS. I'd say the mail server's config looks quite broken.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually it seems it is a common problem here in China. Many people is facing problems using phpMailer with Alicloud servers (ie. http://www.phpernote.com/php-template/430.html http://cloudbbs.org/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=20506) but I do not manage to solve it...

Comment: It makes no sense to disable `stream_socket_client` but still allow `fsockopen`. That second example is using an old version of PHPMailer, which doesn't help, and if you need to make changes like this, the correct approach is to subclass the library and override the things you want to change - you should never edit the library itself as it breaks your ability to upgrade. Overall it looks like you are using a crippled PHP build, talking to a badly configured mail server, so I'm not surprised the code is having trouble! I'd suggest finding an ISP that's not so bad!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback, this put me on right tracks. I was actually using the PHP release from Remi repo to have an up to date one (PHP 5.6) rather than using that one available in official CentOS 6 repos (PHP 5.3). I came back to the official one and now it works!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, the openssl PHP extension is not installed on the Centos server. You should make sure the openssl extension is installed. To check the installed extensions, try the following command on Centos:

```
php -i
```

and look for `openssl` in the resulting text.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have found the following lines:`openssl
    openssl
    OpenSSL support => enabled
    OpenSSL Library Version => OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
    OpenSSL Header Version => OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013

    Directive => Local Value => Master Value
    openssl.cafile => no value => no value
    openssl.capath => no value => no value`

Comment: And also that one: `Registered Stream Socket Transports => tcp, udp, unix, udg, ssl, sslv3, sslv2, tls, tlsv1.0, tlsv1.1, tlsv1.2`